# Jenkins CASC Folder Syntax: How to organise jobs into folders?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the following Jenkins CASC syntax which works well, however I can find nothing in the Jenkins CASC docs on how to simply organise these jobs into folders:

```
unclassified:
  location:
    url: http://0.0.0.0:8888/
security:
  scriptApproval:
    approvedSignatures:
    - staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods putAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String java.lang.Object
jenkins:
  securityRealm:
    local:
      allowsSignup: false
      users:
        # create a user called admin
        - id: "admin"
          password: "admin"
  authorizationStrategy: loggedInUsersCanDoAnything

#numExecutors: 1

#Job Definitions using job-dsl plugin
jobs:
  - file: /usr/local/bootstrap-levels-nprd.groovy
  - file: /usr/local/bootstrap-levels-test-nprd.groovy
  - file: /usr/local/enterprise-caf-level0-certificate-rotation-nprd.groovy
  - file: /usr/local/enterprise-caf-level0-nprd.groovy
  - file: /usr/local/enterprise-destroy-level0-nprd.groovy
  - file: /usr/local/enterprise-caf-level1-nprd.groovy
```

Is there any configuration that would allow me to organise these jobs while still using the general style of configuration of the jobs ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Folders Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-folder/) supplies this functionality, you can add folders similar to how you add jobs:

```
jobs:
  - script: folder('A')
  - script: folder('A/B')
  - script: folder('A/B/C')
  - script: job('A/B/C/myjob')
```

[image]

Comment: I get: java.io.FileNotFoundException: folder('utility/usr/local/bootstrap-levels-nprd.groovy') (No such file or directory)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Comment: Have you found any documentation that describes this syntax in more detail perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot, this feature comes from the [Folders Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-folder/)

Comment: Documentation is buried quite deep [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#folder)